# how to push already selected value in cascading dropdown AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i have made cascading dropdown if i select country based on city will come based on city selection area will come.here i want push some selected country,state,city.i am trying to push using model like $scope.country but its not help me out to move forward

```js
angular.module('test', [])
  .controller('TestController', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        here i already selected countries, state,city from home page         $scope.countries=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("countries"));
console.log($scope.countries);
        //console I'm getting
//India
$scope.state=JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("state"));
console.log($scope.state);
//console I'm getting
//Maharashtra
$scope.city =JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("city"));
console.log($scope.city);
//console I'm getting
//Mumbai
        $scope.countries = {
          'India': {
            'Maharashtra': ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'Nagpur', 'Akola'],
            'Madhya Pradesh': ['Indore', 'Bhopal', 'Jabalpur'],
            'Rajasthan': ['Jaipur', 'Ajmer', 'Jodhpur']
          },
          'USA': {
            'Alabama': ['Montgomery', 'Birmingham'],
            'California': ['Sacramento', 'Fremont'],
            'Illinois': ['Springfield', 'Chicago']
          },
          'Australia': {
            'New South Wales': ['Sydney'],
            'Victoria': ['Melbourne']
          }
        };

        $scope.getCountry = function(val) {
          for (var key in $scope.countries) {
            if ($scope.countries.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if ($scope.countries[key] === val) {
                console.log('You selected: ' + key);
              }
            }
          }
        };
        
        $scope.getCity = function(city, state) {
          for (var key in state) {
            if (state.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
              if (state[key] === city) {
                console.log('You selected: ' + key);
              }
            }
          }
        };

        $scope.alertCity = function(city) {
          console.log('You selected ' + city);
        };
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.AngularJS.org/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="test">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    <div>
      Country:
      <select id="country" ng-model="states" ng-options="country for (country, states) in countries" ng-change="getCountry(states)">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      States:
      <select id="state" ng-disabled="!states" ng-model="cities" ng-options="state for (state,city) in states" ng-change="getCity(cities, states)">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      City:
      <select id="city" ng-disabled="!cities || !states" ng-model="city" ng-change="alertCity(city)">
        <option value=''>Select</option>
        <option ng-repeat="city in cities" value="{{city}}">{{city}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I made a JSFiddle with your code. Could you explain what functionality you are missing?  https://jsfiddle.net/ABr/8un5x3s7/

Comment: That is working I had two pages one is home which contains user details with address fields.if user already entered address I have stored and I need to load in my address page.2nd page my address I have mentioned above if already I had selected India,Maharashtra,Mumbai I need to push this values to dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Write your `ng-options` markup this way:

```
<select ng-options="v as k for (k, v) in countries" ng-model="sCountry"></select>
<select ng-options="v as k for (k, v) in sCountry" ng-model="sState"></select>
<select ng-options="c as c for c in sState" ng-model="sCity"></select>
```

Check out plunk for full code: http://plnkr.co/edit/vsyy5fraMsHgildFJDRA?p=preview

Comment: please check if i have add $scope.sCountry = India;
  $scope.sState = Maharashtra;
  $scope.sCity = Mumbai; its not working